# How to change the font size of a plot's title and axis labels and save it?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Every time I save a plot picture as jpg or png, font size of title and axis label is changed back to default automatically. My code is like this:

```
figure
plot(x, f(x))
title('the smallest n = 1', 'FontSize', 24);
xlabel('x', 'FontSize', 24);
ylabel('x''', 'FontSize', 24);
```

After saving the picture, those font sizes become small again. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Use `export_fig` to export stuff. Matlab save command is.... unreliable

Comment: @Benoit_11 I used matlab's GUI button to save. I would try export_fig as Ander mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Because it just applies for the current figure.

If you want to set the same font size for the whole session, use:

```
set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize', 12);
```

If you want that permanently, put it in your start-up file.

---

By the way, as you can see [**here**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) you can build every "default property" you wish by concatenating `default + class name + property`.

Comment: Sorry, but do you know where i can find the ObjtctType list? In your example the ObjectType is 'Axes'. The link you gave doesn't list out the ObjectType of title or the name of axes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "print" command can solve this problem.

```
fig = figure;
plot(x, f(x));
title('the smallest n = 1', 'FontSize', 24);
xlabel('x', 'FontSize', 24);
ylabel('x''', 'FontSize', 24);
print(fig, 'PicName', '-dpng');
```

The third argument is to specify the format. In my case, I would like to save it to png file.

The font size would remain the values I set now.

Answer (score -1):

Please try and use the following,

```
title(['\fontsize{16}black {\color{magenta}magenta '...
'\color[rgb]{0 .5 .5}teal \color{red}red} black again'])
```

It works for sure